# jGRASP Compilation failed but no error lines

Tags: java

I know this question has been asked before, but there were no straight answers.

I am a high school student in a programming class, and I am having an issue with my IDE, which is jGRASP. I normally use Eclipse, but the class requires me to use jGRASP. When I try to save and run a basic program, I get this error:

[image]

I think it has to do with my pathing, as I use Linux. The current path is /home/arnav/Desktop/School/APCS.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I see "compilation completed" not "failed"

Comment: Sorry about that, wrong picture. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll the output up to see the error.

Most likely you have the JRE installed but not JDK, so there is no java compiler, and the message is that javac was not found, or the JDK is installed but its "bin" directory is not on the system PATH.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be connected with jGRASP project workspace setting. Click the Settings menu, point to Compiler Settings, and then click Workspace. The Settings for workspace dialog box appears.
Under the FLAGS or ARGS section of the dialog box, click the dot inside
the square next to the Compile option and enter the compiler option (-d).
Then click the Apply button.
Click the OK button to close the dialog box, and then compile your
program as usual.

But if (-d) appear two times in your compilation code line, remove one by following the previous instruction above